# Generating a unique random number in constant time

Tags: collections, random, arraylist, runtime, big-o

Is there any way to generate a unique random number in constant time? I'm currently using an arrayList which contains all my possible numbers. It implements Collection and I'm calling the shuffle method on this arrayList. I'm then removing the 0th element from the arrayList to get the unique random number, but I believe this cannot be constant time for 2 reasons:

- the remove method is O(n)
- Collection.shuffle is O(n)

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Do you want to select a single value from the set, or do you actually want a subset of size k sampled without replacement?  If a subset, is there a fixed value for k or some other stopping criterion?  Also, it wouldn't hurt to know what language you're working in.

Answer (score 0):

Collection.shuffle is indeed O(n), but it only needs to be called once. If you're getting n random numbers, that time sort of diffuses into the remaining operations. (this is the kind of idea behind amortized analysis, which seems necessary for your problem: either you want "amortized deterministic constant time", or "expected constant time", as one might do with a dictionary)

the remove method is O(n) in general, but if you repeatedly remove the last element instead of the first, the array doesn't have to constantly shift its elements down, so it's actually O(1)--it's just that it's O(n) in the average and worst cases.